# Editing PyQT5 SimpleTreeModelExample to work for a list of lists instead of tab separated text by line

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pyqt5, qtreeview

I am trying to use the SimplyTreeModel example from pyqt5 to create a model that I can use for a treeview GUI. I am parsing a folder of json files and their properties to return a list of lists. I'll later want to store a lot of properties to show in a property pane when a certain item is clicked, but for now I'll keep the data structure simple.

The treeview that I want to show would only be two levels of hierarchy. The parents would be the JSON file names, and the children would be the specific item callouts that are stored inside each JSON file.

The link for code I'm trying to alter can be viewed here. I think the main thing I would have to change is the setupModelData function of the TreeModel class. I have provided the code used to parse a txt file line by line and use indents to set up the parent structure. If you would rather I put it all directly into this window, let me know and I can make an edit.

(https://github.com/pyside/Examples/blob/master/examples/itemviews/simpletreemodel/simpletreemodel.py)

```
def setupModelData(self, lines, parent):
        parents = [parent]
        indentations = [0]

        number = 0

        while number < len(lines):
            position = 0
            while position < len(lines[number]):
                if lines[number][position] != b' ':
                    break
                position += 1

            lineData = lines[number][position:].trimmed()

            if lineData:
                # Read the column data from the rest of the line.
                columnData = [s for s in lineData.split('\t') if s]

                if position > indentations[-1]:
                    # The last child of the current parent is now the new
                    # parent unless the current parent has no children.

                    if parents[-1].childCount() > 0:
                        parents.append(parents[-1].child(parents[-1].childCount() - 1))
                        indentations.append(position)

                else:
                    while position < indentations[-1] and len(parents) > 0:
                        parents.pop()
                        indentations.pop()

                # Append a new item to the current parent's list of children.
                parents[-1].appendChild(TreeItem(columnData, parents[-1]))

            number += 1
```

instead, I want to set up my data to parse the list of lists and build into the model. Here is an example of my data.

`[['deliveryLog_2023_03_30.json',   [['1item1',     'property1',     '2023_03_30']]],  ['deliveryLog_2023_04_03.json',   [['2item1',     '2property1',     '2023_04_03']]],  ['deliveryLog_2023_04_10.json',   [['3item1', '3property1', '2023_04_10'],    ['3item2',     '3property2',     '2023_04_10'],    ['3item3',     '3property3',     '2023_04_10'],    ['3item4',     '3property4',     '2023_04_10']]]]`

So in this example, I would want the parents to be the three dated json logs. The children that would show in the treeview are the items under each json. Later, I would create a property window that would show the properties.

So far, I have tried various edits to rewrite the logic in the setupModelData function to work with this list of lists. I have tried to write out logic in a for loop for printing that I have working on a test code file, but I can't figure out what I need to do to get it working in the model. I am new to model view programming and struggle with understanding how to debug/get to the root of issues.

```
parents = []
testnum = 1
for item in cleaned_df:
    parents.append(item[0])
    for child_item in item[1]:
        child_data = (child_item[0])
        print(f'FileName: {parents[-1]} FILE {testnum}: {child_data}')
    testnum += 1
```

this is a stab I took at trying to implement it into the function:

```
#Kev Replacement code section---------------
for item in cleaned_df:
    parents.append(item[0])
    for child_item in item[1]:
        parents.append(parents[-1].child(parents[-1].childCount() - 1))
        parents[-1].appendChild(TreeItem(child_item[0], parents[-1]))
```

Any help with how I can the model to load into a treeview properly would be greatly appreciated. I've been banging my head against this for a couple days and am quite lost.

Comment: I'd start by using a more explicit for loop, for example: `for jsonParent, children in cleaned_df:`. This would be much more readable (which means that you can understand and debug it more easily) than `item[0]` and `item[1]`. Then create the parent, iterate through children with `for item in children:`, create the TreeItem with the item data, add it to the parent and, finally (in the main for loop) append the parent to the model. If you want a more comprehensive answer I'd suggest you to [edit] your post and provide a self-contained [mre] in order to make it easier for us to show you code.